# Listening on ip address with socket : address already in use

Tags: python, linux, sockets

I'm trying to listen on a certain ip address so I use a socket but when I specify the udp_IP, I get "address already in use".

Is there a way I can reuse the ip address for both my application and my listener?

I don't have a very good networking knowledge, any help would be great.

Comment: Can you provide your code example?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the localhost IP address, that's about the closest you could come to the server being a listener and application, however you can not run different services/applications on the same port, you could create virtual machines maybe and use port tunneling to run multiple services

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you **cannot** use the same port or socket with different programs. If what you want is stopping the listener and start the application in that port, open a terminal and type:

```
sudo netstat -nlp | grep:yourSocketNumberGoesHere
```

This is to get the *process ID* of the program running. Then just use `kill` followed by the *process ID* you get to kill the program. Then, try starting your application.

If what you want is using 2 different programs in the same socket or port, you can't, without maybe doing something more complex (which I do not know).

You could use 2 ports that communicate with each other if you want the 2 programs to interact.